# Barcodes on membership cards?

Tags: civimember

We use Civicrm to manage our membership database. Members get in to the museums free. My front desk staff would love it if it was possible for Civicrm to generate a barcode for each member, that would be printed on their card, that they could then scan when they use their membership to visit the museum. This would help us see how often different members visit. 
Is this possible? 
I've seen a variety of thread about event check-in with barcodes, but nothing with memberships more broadly. . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been some work relating to QR codes and barcodes linked below. It sounds like the model you might need to aim for is to make cividiscount work with QR/bar codes then some of the bits of what is required could work.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/qr-code-checkin

[Quickly entering attendance with barcodes](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4634/quickly-entering-attendance-with-barcodes)

Comment: Thanks for linking these! I mentioned these resources to my computer programmer husband, and he wrote me some quick code to extend Fuzion Tokens to insert a qr code based on the url that is accessed when adding an activity. We're rolling out some testing with it to see if it will work smoothly, but I'm optimistic.

Comment: sounds good. if it works then pls push a patch through to the extension and we will test it too. handy husband :-)

Answer (score 1):

Kai, welcome to civicrm stackexchange. I am afraid to say that this is not supported at the moment in Civi and also i doubt if there are any extension available for this. But you can achieve this if you have experience in programming than you can write an extension and implement hook to create token that will generate barcode.

Thanks

Pradeep